# PS2 classics on Vita?

Tags: psn, ps-vita

I just saw a news post that Trapt for PS2 is coming to PSN, "for PS3 and Vita". I didn't know the Vita could play PS2 games.

Do all the PS2 games on the PlayStation Store work? If not, is there a compatibility list somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they don't, it's a port (separate for PS3 and Vita). Hence, there is no such compatibily list.